# How to move VBO button to under view

Tags: views

I'm just using Views Bulk Operations for the first time.

VBO augments Views  " ...by showing a checkbox in front of each displayed row, and adding a select box on top of the View containing operations that can be applied."

I have it all working as it should, however, I would like to move this select box and button to UNDER the view (under the table that I am making in my view). I've been looking at this for sometime, and haven't been able to figure out how to do this. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can modify the form by implementing `hook_form_alter()` either in a custom module or in *template.php* in your theme.

Here's a code snippet that brings the table above the other form elements by lowering its weight ([source](https://www.drupal.org/node/848772#comment-8303593)):

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if (strpos($form_id,  'your_vbo_form_id') !== FALSE) {
      $form['output']['#weight'] = -99; //Decrease the weight of output to rise it above other elements.
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.

I have already tried that approach, and found that (unless I am doing something wrong)  it doesn't work. My code was exactly the same as yours, as I got it from the same place.

The results I got were that the button and drop down move down a little, in fact they ended up literally on top of (in front of) the top of the table, obscuring it, and still near the top. Do you have any idea why that might be happening?

Comment: Gotcha. (It helps, by the way, to include methods that you've already tried in your question.) I've just tested it and it works perfectly for me. Is it possibly a CSS issue? In your HTML output (using developer tools or view page source), check to see whether `<fieldset id="edit-select">` occurs after `<table>`.

Comment: This solution worked for me. You might try a `dpm` on `$form_id` to make sure that you got it right. I originally had it formatted like `vbo-form-id` instead of `vbo_form_id`.